# 'Handsontable' is undefined. after publishing

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

In my machine (windows 7) the handsontable works perfectly. but when I publish to a Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7, framewok 4.0, all works great (css, some .js), but when it reaches to the handsontable definition it breaks into an error:

'Handsontable' is undefined

in this line specifically:

```
$(nomGrillaProveedor).handsontable({
            colHeaders: false,
            colWidths: [530],
            minSpareRows: 1,
            maxRows: 1,
```

This is how I reference to the .js of handsontable:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.handsontable.full.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I also changed the first section of the jquery.handsontable.full.js code by deleting the 'Var' declaration. someone explained that the Var caused conflict...

```
Handsontable = { //class namespace
  extension: {}, //extenstion namespace
  helper: {} //helper namespace
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can it be for case sensitive?? in the declaration it's Handsontable, with H in caps, but in the aspx it's handsontable  with the h in lower case.